# How to pass a value to read input before being prompted?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have shell script prompting an answer y/n. at the prompt before giving input, I used control-c signal which calls Signal Handling function. In Signal Handling function there is a prompt "q" to exit or "y" and "y" should be used with the FIRST read prompt.

I tried to (( echo "y" | read )) but didn't work

This is part of my script:

```
IntHandle ()
{ 
  echo -e "\nUse 'q' to quit "
  read var1 
  if [[ $var1 == q ]]
  then
      exit 1
  else
      echo "y" | read ----->here I need "y" to be an input to read prompt 
                         directly and being saved in "ans" variable in 
                         main body where I used control-c 
  fi
}


 trap 'IntHandle' SIGINT
 read -p "no valid user id entered, new user ids? [y\n]: " ans ----> here 
                              used control-c signal before give y/n to ans
if [[ $ans == "y" ]]
then 
     read -p " username :" name
fi
       .
       .
       .
       .
```

## .

output should be like below:

no valid user id entered, new user ids? [y\n]: #control-c entered

' Use 'q' to quit '   y ------> here "y" entered rather "q" in Siganl Handeling 
                             function then it is saved in "ans" variable 
                             which gets the condition true to prompt a username.

usernames: Larry -----> the name which is entered after true condition. . . .

Answer (score 2):

This is a X-Y problem. Why on earth use `read` for setting a variable in a script?

Set it the normal way; `ans=y`

This would make the function look like this:

```
IntHandle ()
{ 
  echo -e "\nUse 'q' to quit "
  read var1 
  if [[ $var1 == q ]]
  then
      exit 1
  else
      ans=y
  fi
}
```

Comment: First, I did before "ans=y"  but did not work because I am still being prompted to enter "y" or "n" in the first prompt which it should not. Just when I enter "y" rather than "q" in the function prompt, it would set "ans" variable by "y" and skip me the prompt.

Comment: I need to skip the stdin in the first prompt when I use control-c signal before giving "y" or "n" to ans variable.

Comment: No, you need to modify the flow of the program to skip that prompt if the value is set. Whenever ^C is pressed, your code will jump to IntHandle(). How can that be used to skip the prompt? I'm trying to nudge you along here, because, as I said, you have put your eyes on a solution, which is *wrong*.